# how to get last updated field in DataSet row?

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

Any idea how to get last updated field in **DataSet** row?

I mean in **C#** is there anything like `select @@identity` in **sql**?

Comment: just use a select on the max(id)

Comment: @ Mortalus: that would give you last inserted (assuming identity column)

Comment: Mitch,what if i get results to the DataSet from SQLDB

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `column` that have `DateTime` in it. When you update your record, set the 
`DateTime` of your record to `DateTime.Now` and `Atlast select Max(DateTimeColumn)`.

Some may prefer that `column in DB` for keeping records of last update.